# My Android App hangs on SharedPreferences, but only in Android 5

Tags: android

An odd one here. I've built an app in Android Studio which is working perfectly in Android 4 (4.4.2), but it just stopping on Android 5.0.2. It's not throwing up any errors, just stopping. 
Going line by line, it seems to be focussed on the SharedPreferences file, which it's not loading.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
   try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("appname", MODE_PRIVATE );
        currentlyTracking = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("currentlyTracking", false);
```

So, on Android 4, going line by line, when I get to the currentlytracking line, I can view the contents of the SharedPreferences file in the Variables window, and the app works. On Android 5, when I get to the currentlytracking line, none of the variables show up, and it just says 'Collecting data'. The app then stops if I try to continue on.

Interestingly, if I change the name of the Sharedpreferences file, it will create a new file but then fail to save to it.

This is only happening on Android 5, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm wondering if it's failing to create the file rather than failing to load it.

Comment: Try a full uninstall and reinstall of your app. Your "Interestingly..." paragraph suggests that there was a change in the Linux user ID for your app (e.g., you added or changed `android:sharedUserId`), but your existing internal storage is owned by the previous Linux user ID.